# Get mean based on the other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I've a dataset which has 2 columns named : 'rate' 'rest_type' and they have values like :

```
rate   rest_type
3.4    dining
4      casual
3      cafe   
3.4    delivery
4      mexian
3      italian
4.4    indian
4      south_indian
3      cafe
```

Now I want to calculate the mean of only the rate which has corresponding columns as 'dining' & 'cafe' only

How can i do that ?  Thanks in advance

Please check the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[df['rest_type'].isin(['cafe', 'dining']), 'rate'].mean()
```

output: `3.1333333333333333`

Intermediate:

```
df.loc[df['rest_type'].isin(['cafe', 'dining']), 'rate']

0    3.4
2    3.0
8    3.0
Name: rate, dtype: float64
```